# how can I create shot down short cut on keyboard

Tags: shortcut-keys

question is simple 
how can I create shot down short cut on keyboard
so when I press that buttons computer will shot down

Answer (score 2):

There is already a shortcut for this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key

I assume your case it's <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>printscr</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>. But look it up in the table provided there.

Answer (score 0):

you can also create your own shortcuts by using xbindkeys, see this tutorial:
http://www.butlerpc.net/blog/2011/01/using-xbindkeys-on-ubuntu-linux-to-remap-key-commands/